# Disqus comments count taking long to update

Tags: plugins, functions, comments, javascript, disqus

When I post something, the comments count doesn't change, sometimes it takes between 10 minutes to 1 hour (or even more) for the comments count to appear as '0'. And if i leave a comment, is the same until the count is updated to '1'.

I've tried almost everything and none of them worked. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
        <script>
            /**
             *  RECOMMENDED CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT AND UNCOMMENT THE SECTION BELOW TO INSERT DYNAMIC VALUES FROM YOUR PLATFORM OR CMS.
             *  LEARN WHY DEFINING THESE VARIABLES IS IMPORTANT: https://disqus.com/admin/universalcode/#configuration-variables
             */

            var disqus_config = function () {
                this.page.url = '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>';  // Replace PAGE_URL with your page's canonical URL variable
                this.page.identifier = '<?php dsq_identifier_for_post($post); ?>'; // Replace PAGE_IDENTIFIER with your page's unique identifier variable
            };

            (function() {  // REQUIRED CONFIGURATION VARIABLE: EDIT THE SHORTNAME BELOW
                var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

                s.src = '//mysite.disqus.com/embed.js';  // IMPORTANT: Replace EXAMPLE with your forum shortname!

                s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
                (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
            })();
        </script>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>

    <!-- Comments count on each post -->
    <span class="disqus-comment-count comments" data-disqus-url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#disqus_thread"></span>

    <!-- JavaScript on footer -->
<script id="dsq-count-scr" src="//mysite.disqus.com/count.js" async></script>
```

Comment: Hi gabriel, are you using a cache plugin? Did you try clearing your cache or using incognito mode to view the results?

Comment: I'm not using any cache plugin, with clean cache in incognito mode the results are the same